# Users getting empty folder instead of "Access Denied"

Tags: document-library, permissions, access-denied

Our organization is in the process of migrating to SharePoint 2013, and we are experiencing a strange issue and we're unsure if it is intended behavior.

We have a document library with several sub folders. We are granting access to folders via different SharePoint groups.

The problem is that when users click on a link to one of sub folders that they do not have access to they are not receiving the "Access Denied" error. Instead, they are able to get into the folder itself, but they are not seeing any of the documents. The only time they are getting an "Access Denied" error is if we point them directly to a document within a folder.

Just to be clear, the access is being granted at the folder level, and they only have "limited access" on the document library level.

We have done a lot of searching and can't find anything specific to this issue, so I thought I'd post it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour in SharePoint 2013.  I guess this is considered as enhancement,  instead of showing Access Denied page for every possible clicks,  how the users see only what they have access to,  it really does not help in showing something that they do not have access.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to change this default behavior? Our primary concern is that user's don't have the option to "Request Access" to the folder like they did in the past. It can also make user's believe that the folder itself if just empty, instead of thinking they need access.

Comment: Instead of giving direct access to the user,  make sure that your permission settings uses Gropus,  and in the groups you have option of "Allow users to join/leave this group" make sure to mark them as "Yes".  See if this helps